# Clojure Leiningen offline install

Tags: clojure, installation, leiningen

I'm working in a very restrictive environment, I cannot execute any curl or wget scripts like lein.sh/.bat, nor can I "git" the code.
I have the leiningen-x.x.x-standalone.jar which does not make up a complete leiningen setup.
How can I setup a complete leiningen, offline? is there something like a "complete" download? If not what are the essential parts? What is the required file system layout?

Answer (score 6):

the "correct" approach for [working with maven in a protected enterprise setting](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/) would be to setup a repo mirror, populate it with all the jars you need, and then add it to your ~/.m2/settings.xml file to mirror everything.

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>archiva.default</id>   
      <url>http://my.mirror.com:8080/archiva/repository/internal</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

this is a lot of work up front, though it can pay off in the long run because you can use the mirror internally for later projects (and to make downloads faster)

copying a working .m2 directory is a perfectly respectable hack as well

Answer (score 3):

Copying .m2 directory and the lein sh script should do the trick.